# In Java concurrency tutorial in fork/join section, how is the "computeDirectly" function executed via "invokeAll"?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, fork-join

In [the fork/join chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) in the official Java Concurrency tutorial, it has the following partial-example code.

I understand if the image-array size is less than the threshold (100,000), then it's computed directly (`computeDirectly`). Otherwise it's split in half, and two `ForkBlur` objects are created and invoked (`invokeAll`). What I don't understand is how `invokeAll` ends up executing the `computeDirectly` function for those pieces.

How is the `computeDirectly` function called for arrays that are larger than the threshold? (The pieces it's split into.)

```
public class ForkBlur extends RecursiveAction {
   private int[] mSource;
   private int mStart;
   private int mLength;
   private int[] mDestination;

   // Processing window size; should be odd.
   private int mBlurWidth = 15;

   public ForkBlur(int[] src, int start, int length, int[] dst) {
      mSource = src;
      mStart = start;
      mLength = length;
      mDestination = dst;
   }

   protected void computeDirectly() {
      int sidePixels = (mBlurWidth - 1) / 2;
      for (int index = mStart; index < mStart + mLength; index++) {
         // Calculate average.
         float rt = 0, gt = 0, bt = 0;
         for (int mi = -sidePixels; mi <= sidePixels; mi++) {
            int mindex = Math.min(Math.max(mi + index, 0),
                                  mSource.length - 1);
            int pixel = mSource[mindex];
            rt += (float)((pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16)
                 / mBlurWidth;
            gt += (float)((pixel & 0x0000ff00) >>  8)
                 / mBlurWidth;
            bt += (float)((pixel & 0x000000ff) >>  0)
                 / mBlurWidth;
         }

         // Reassemble destination pixel.
         int dpixel = (0xff000000    ) |
               (((int)rt) << 16) |
               (((int)gt) <<  8) |
               (((int)bt) <<  0);
         mDestination[index] = dpixel;
      }
   }

  ...
```

And this separate piece which calls it:

```
protected static int sThreshold = 100000;

protected void compute() {
   if (mLength < sThreshold) {
      computeDirectly();
      return;
   }

   int split = mLength / 2;

   invokeAll(new ForkBlur(mSource, mStart, split, mDestination),
           new ForkBlur(mSource, mStart + split, mLength - split,
                     mDestination));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
invokeAll(new ForkBlur(mSource, mStart, split, mDestination),
       new ForkBlur(mSource, mStart + split, mLength - split,
                 mDestination));
```

ends up invoking the `compute` method of `ForkBlur` which, if you've split it to a small enough threshold, will execute `computeDirectly` by passing through the `if` condition here

```
if (mLength < sThreshold) {
    computeDirectly();
    return;
}
```

So one big task gets split into two (or more) smaller tasks, which may get split again, and again, until the tasks are small enough to be run.

Comment: That's what I was missing. Every piece gets smaller and smaller, until it reaches the threshold. Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis.